# Fixed row on the bottom of grid

Tags: javascript, extjs

[image]
I have summary row in my table. But user can see it only when he will scroll down all grid. But it could be better, if summary row will be fixed at the bottom of the grid, and it will be visible always, when the grid is shown. How can I modify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how to fix a row like you're suggesting, but for something that needs to be visible 100% of the time, have you thought about adding a top bar or a bottom bar that displays these values?  You can use the [displayfield xtype](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Display) to show text in such a place.  I'm doing this in several projects.

Comment: I override standart summary and now it created docked bar with html code of my data...

Comment: @Nikita Can you please let me know how you created a docked bar aligned with grid columns

Comment: @Devendra Manually. I take width of column and set width of html div in docked element.